# AngularJS Show List Items based on ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to create some functionality where the user would have an input box and all the data (li's) below are hidden. 
Then when a user types into the input box, those li's that match that text are show.

What would the best way to do this using angular? I've set up plunker below:
http://plnkr.co/edit/T6JOBJE4LrAtshbmaoPk?p=preview

I was thinking of setting the li's to:

```
li {
 display: none;
}
```

and then was going to try an ng-if with the ng-model as the value. Something like this:

```
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Search</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search">
  </div>    
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in data | filter:search " ng-if="!search">{{x.name}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction? Even if its just explaining the logic.

Comment: Why would you use display:none, since you want the lis to be visible? The filter will take care of only adding the matched items to the DOM. And why use `ng-if="!search"`? Have you rzad the documentation for filter, because it has an example showing what you want: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: I think the `ng-if` should be `<li ng-repeat="x in data | filter:search " ng-if="search">{{x.name}}</li>`.will show the result if filter is applied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set ng-show attribute to your `<ul>` tag, where you will watch on length of `search` variable and if it's greater that zero, your list with filtered results will be shown. So, you don't need any css.

```
<ul ng-show="search.length">
  <li ng-repeat="x in data | filter:search ">{{x.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

[Demo on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TkdjxUGZ0VI2vuiqqkj4).

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is the filter matches on the empty search string. You could create a custom filter to handle this, something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/i4lsuVUmOLO3pbISu7FR?p=preview

```
$scope.filterName = function(datum) {
  console.log($scope.search, datum);
  return $scope.search !== '' && datum.name.indexOf($scope.search) !== -1;
};
```

Used in the template like:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in data | filter:filterName">{{x.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Then you would have greater control over the filter if you want to tweak it in future.